# change language in CK FINDER 3

Tags: laravel, ckfinder

hope you all doing well,

i'm in a project using Laravel, and right now i'm facing a little problem with the language of CKFinder. it's in Chinese.

i have used the following commands in both vendor/admin-ck/ckeditor/config.js and vendor/admin-ck/ckfinder/config.js

```
var config = {};
config.language = 'en';
CKFinder.popup( config );

config.defaultLanguage = 'en';
```

but it's still in chinese.

is there any way that i dont have to "hard translate" the Json language file?

Answer (score 1):

Refer link [1]:  https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3/?mobile=/api/CKFinder.Config

```
CKFinder.popup( {
    language: 'de'
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

I Had to change CKUPLOADER.blade.php

and added
config.language = 'pt-br';
config.defaultLanguage = 'pt-br';

to file: ckfinder/config.js